# How can I find out if a strongly typed table contains a value from another strongly typed table in C# using Linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have two strongly tabled tables for Customers with Locations, which have the columns "CustomerCode" and "Location".

In Customer A, there are the following rows:

```
"A", 1
"A", 2
"A", 3
```

In Customer B, there are the following rows:

```
"B", 2
"B", 5
"B", 6
```

How can I use Linq to workout whether Customer B has any Locations, the same as Customer A.

I want to do something like this foreach but in linq:

```
var doesExist = false; 
foreach(var a in customersA)
{
   if (customersB.Select(b => b.Location).Contains(a.Location))
   {
      doesExist = true;
      break;
   }
 }
```

For example, I want to do something like this:

`customersA.Select(a => a.Location).Any(customersB.Select(b => b.Location)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note I'm assuming you want one bool that determines whether or not there is any customer in both tables that share a Location.  AND assuming you don't care which customer(s) had the match - just that there was a match at all.

If you want it all in LINQ statements, nest the Any statements, then compare the Location property:

```
bool sameLocationFound = customersB.Any(b => customersA.Any(a => a.Location == b.Location));
```

I read this code as "find whether any customer B exists such that any customer A shares a location with B".

Comment: Thanks for that mate, this is exactly what I was after. I'll make use of this in my code.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`Intersect`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.intersect?view=netframework-4.8) like below

```
var location_in_CustA = customersA.Select(a => a.Location);
var location_in_CustB = customersB.Select(b => b.Location);

var intersectionRecords = location_in_CustA.Intersect(location_in_CustB);
var exists = intersectionRecords.Count() > 1;
```

> Produces the set intersection of two sequences.

Comment: Thanks for that, looks interesting.

Comment: It does thank you but the one liner above bool sameLocationFound = customersB.Any(b => customersA.Any(a => a.Location == b.Location)); was pretty much what I wanted.

Answer (score 2):

Another way is using `let` keyword:

```
var query = (from c in customerA
             let locations = customerB.Select(c => c.Location)
             where locations.Any(l => l == c.Location)
            ).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.